# how do sour brewers manage their local wild yeast in the air?

Tags: yeast, sour, wild-yeast

Can anyone describe the general process you manage the levels of wild yeast in air?

I'm thinking have a maltose solution exposed and measure the change in specific gravity of it over time while opening/closing airflow from your vents and changing the settings on those large air filters for people with allergies

Comment: FWIW, most commercial brewers making sour beer aren't doing it with wild microbes romantically caught in the wind.  They are pitching blends of microbial cultures that were identified and purified in the lab.  Those that have done some true 'wild' ferments it was trial and error.  Sometimes they'd catch something nice, sometimes they don't.

Comment: man, that's not romantic at all lol. Do you have any insight to Jester King? It's in Austin, I haven't been able to meet em yet. I heard they selectively pressured their local wild yeast over time, my source is good but I haven't heard from the horse yet

Comment: I see your blog now, nvm. Nice blog btw

Are there any other breweries you've heard of gunslinging and using yeast in the air any more so I can research?

Comment: Allagash in Portland ME does this annually.  They built a coolship and and a traditional room for it.

Comment: Cheers! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally the wort is put in a cold ship over night to inoculate . This is a large shallow vat to maximize air exposure for spontanuous fermintation.

Once wort is inoculated the growth phase happens pretty fast, and the brewer is happy.

I don't know of any method outside of a lab to test if there is X many yeast cells in Y volume of air.

Most of these famous wild strains have been isolated for traditional pitching.

Comment: seems dirty to keep callin em "wild" at this point lol. I think I'm confusing lambics, which are literally wild, with sours, which use bacteria

Comment: @codyc4321 I don't think these souring bacteria are airborne.

Comment: the bacteria definitely aren't, but I thought the yeast were in sours. I think I associated the sour lambic with all sours and lumped them into a narrow category.

But this week I'll be readin, because it seems sours are taking over for now and overtaking IPAs in demand

Comment: @codyc4321 There are several ways to make a sour, basically split into two categories. Kettle souring (adding acid) and having a bacteria added just before or with the yeast pitch so the alcohol produced by the yeast kills the bacteria before it produced too much acid. The later is definatly an art of the craft.

Comment: Kettle souring isn't the addition of acid.  Kettle souring is acheived by holding the run off from the mash warm and letting the natural lactic acid producing bacteria from the grain sour the wort.  Then once the wort has soured sufficiently the boil is begun (maybe 2 or three days later in some cases).  You can add acid in the kettle and call it kettle souring but that's no different than adding the acid in the bright tank after a fermentation.  Kettle souring is normally a natural process relying on microbes.

Comment: @brewchez thank you, yes that was a missuse of the term. So basically you can sour two ways, add acids or allow bacteria to make it. Both can be done at various stages of brewing. http://www.newschoolbeer.com/2015/06/how-kettle-souring-is-making-sour-beer-cheap-and-affordable.html - kettle souring uses bacteria but limits brewhouse infection on since the wort is soured preboil.

Comment: FWIW - lacto b bacteria IS airborne when you mill raw grains. I try to mill  away from my fermentations. I used to mill and bright tank in the same basement room, and there's dust everywhere. :-)